# maximum no of websocket connection with a container running with istio envoy proxy

Tags: docker, websocket, istio, envoyproxy

I seem to be hitting a limit on maximum no of websocket connection within a container with istio proxy

It seems to run out at 1024 (which seems like default)

I also tried increasing my --default-ulimit for nofiles to 102400:102400 but am suspecting its limited by istio

I also tried adding DestinationPolicy but that didnt help too

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
#kind: CircuitBreaker.SimpleCircuitBreakerPolicy
kind: DestinationPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-cb-ploicy
  namespace: default # optional (default is "default")
spec:
  destination:
    name: apiserver
    #name: apiserver.default.svc.cluster.local
    #namespace: default # optional (default is metadata namespace field)
  circuitBreaker:
    simpleCb:
      maxConnections: 102400
      httpMaxPendingRequests: 102400
      httpMaxRequests: 102400
      httpMaxRequestsPerConnection: 102400
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below somehow made envoy recognize and update the destination policy

```
  httpDetectionInterval: 1s
  sleepWindow: 3m
  httpMaxEjectionPercent: 100
```